# Possible to Publish swf from Flash Pro directly to Amazon S3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, amazon-s3, flash-cs5, flash-cs5.5

I naively tried to put the path for amazon S3 into the publish path in flash professional.

It gave me the standarad erro, "Error Creating swf movie file. Destination directory does not exist. Change your publish settings."

It is possible to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you can mount the server as a volume ([Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/) can do this), then you can publish the SWF to a location on that volume.